# ORA-06502 on Oracle function while using DOMNode

Tags: xml, oracle, dom, plsql, oracle12c

I am trying to execute a plsql code on an Oracle 12c.

Describing the environment:

First, register the XML schema.

```
BEGIN
-- Register the schema
DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.registerSchema('http://www.example.com/fvInteger.xsd',
'<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="FeatureVector">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="feature" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="64" maxOccurs="64"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>',
   TRUE, TRUE, FALSE);
END;
/
```

Then create the table

```
CREATE TABLE fv_XML_64 (
   id    NUMBER,
   fv  XMLTYPE)
   XMLTYPE complex_obj STORE AS OBJECT RELATIONAL
      XMLSCHEMA "http://www.example.com/fvInteger.xsd"
      ELEMENT "FeatureVector";
```

I am getting the error:

> SELECT mahalanobis_distance_XML((SELECT fv FROM fv_XML_64 c WHERE
>   c.id=1000), (SELECT fv FROM fv_XML_64 c WHERE c.id=988)) FROM DUAL;
>   SELECT mahalanobis_distance_XML((SELECT fv FROM fv_XML_64 c WHERE
>   c.id=1000), (SELECT fv FROM fv_XML_64 c WHERE c.id=988)) FROM DUAL
>          * ERRO na linha 1: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: erro numerico ou de valor ORA-06512: em "HIGIIA.MAHALANOBIS_DISTANCE_XML", line 50

The function I am trying to execute:

```
create or replace FUNCTION mahalanobis_distance_xml(
  innXML XMLType,
  outXML XMLType
) RETURN number
IS
  total NUMBER := 0;
  docInn xmldom.DOMDocument;
  docOut xmldom.DOMDocument;
  nInn xmldom.DOMNode;
  nInn2 xmldom.DOMNode;
  nOut xmldom.DOMNode;
  aux NUMBER;
  max_d NUMBER :=0;
  nlInn xmldom.DOMNodeList;
  nlInn2 xmldom.DOMNodeList;
  nlOut xmldom.DOMNodeList;
  TYPE tbNumber IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  TYPE tbNumberMatrix IS TABLE OF tbNumber INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  l INTEGER;
  l_out INTEGER;
  mA tbNumberMatrix;
  mD tbNumberMatrix;
  x_minus_y INTEGER_ARRAY := INTEGER_ARRAY();
BEGIN
--Converte os atributos xmltype para DOMDocuments.
docInn := dbms_xmldom.newDOMDocument(innXML);
docOut := dbms_xmldom.newDOMDocument(outXML);

nlInn := xmldom.getElementsByTagName(docInn, '*');
nlInn2 := xmldom.getElementsByTagName(docInn, '*');
nlOut := xmldom.getElementsByTagName(docOut, '*');
l := xmldom.getLength(nlInn);
l_out := xmldom.getLength(nlOut);

IF l = l_out THEN 

        x_minus_y.extend(l) ;

        FOR i IN 1..l LOOP
            FOR j IN 1..l LOOP
                mA(i)(j) := 0;
                mD(i)(j) := 0;
            END LOOP;
        END LOOP;


        FOR i IN 1..l LOOP
            nInn := xmldom.item(nlInn, i);
                        nOut := xmldom.item(nlOut, i);
            x_minus_y(i)  := ABS(xmldom.getNodeValue(DBMS_XMLDOM.getFirstChild(nInn)) -  xmldom.getNodeValue(DBMS_XMLDOM.getFirstChild(nOut)));
            FOR j IN 1..l LOOP
                nInn2 := xmldom.item(nlInn, j);
                mD(i)(j) := ABS(xmldom.getNodeValue(DBMS_XMLDOM.getFirstChild(nInn2)) - xmldom.getNodeValue(DBMS_XMLDOM.getFirstChild(nOut)));

...
```

The error is at this part of the code:

```
        FOR j IN 1..l LOOP
            nInn2 := xmldom.item(nlInn, j);
            mD(i)(j) := ABS(xmldom.getNodeValue(DBMS_XMLDOM.getFirstChild(nInn2)) - xmldom.getNodeValue(DBMS_XMLDOM.getFirstChild(nOut)));
```

What is wrong?

I got this in the docs:

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error string
>
> Cause: An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
>   occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
>   assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
>   attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
>   declared NUMBER(2).
>
> Action: Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared
>   so that values do not violate constraints.

But I cannot find what is wrong in the case of the presented function.

Comment: What data type is `fv_XML_64.fv`? What are the actual values being passed in, for those two IDs? Are all the node values really numbers?

Comment: updated the question with the information you required.